# Create table with multicolumn using IEEE Access template

Tags: tables, multicolumn, ieeeaccess

I want to create a table, I implement this code:

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{Operation on weighted feature detectors}
    \label{tab:tabel_maxop}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{100pt}|p{25pt}|p{25pt}|}
        \hline
        Operation Mode&
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{mAP (\%)}\\
        \hline
        & Data1& Data2\\
        \hline
        Method1 (Original)& 32.5& 16.9\\
        Method1 (No1)& 29.7& 16.8\\
        Method1 (No2)& 32.1& 17.0\\
        Method1 (No3)& 31.5& 18.1\\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And the output is: 
[image]

What I want is:

- Remove line below "Operation Mode"
- Make "Operation Mode" in the center of box without affecting position of words "Method1" and so on

For centering, I write `\begin{tabular}{c...}` but it will affect position of all "Method1"

I have read other sources but they add another package and I **dont** want to use packages except the ones specified in the IEEE Access template.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which we can test as it is. When you provide only code fragment, we need to reconstruct your document knowing, that you already have it ... This is not fun. Please help us to help you!
- since you not provide MWE, so far solution for table consider standard `article` document class. Conversion to your document class I left to you. In both the table design is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{Operation on weighted feature detectors}
    \label{tab:tabel_maxop}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{100pt}|p{25pt}|p{25pt}|}
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Operation Mode}}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{mAP (\%)}\\
        \cline{2-3}
                    & Data1& Data2\\
        \hline
Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9\\
Method1 (No1)       & 29.7 & 16.8\\
Method1 (No2)       & 32.1 & 17.0\\
Method1 (No3)       & 31.5 & 18.1\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Corrected is horizontal position of the first column's header position.

Comment: Thank you again! I will remember MWE next time. And, "Operation Mode' is not center horizontally?

Comment: Ah, overlooked this request. It will be corrected asap